# Avoid Creating duplicate task

Tags: apex, visualforce, tasks

Below code is working really fine, but the problem I am facing is the task is related to contact twice.

```
 List<Task> cvTask = new List<Task>();
    Task cv;       

    String[] toAddressesList = EmailToAddresses.split(',');

    for(String toContactId : toAddressesList) {
        cv = new Task();
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> msgList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage msg = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        msg.setTargetObjectId(toContactId);
        msg.setFileAttachments(fileList);
        msg.setHTMLBody(htmlEmailBody);
        msg.setSubject(EmailSubject);
        msgList.add(msg);            

        List<Messaging.SendEmailResult> sendResult = Messaging.sendEmail(msgList);
        System.debug('Email Result' + sendResult); 

        if (sendResult.get(0).isSuccess()) {
            cv.Subject = 'Email:' + EmailSubject;
            cv.WhoId = toContactId;
            cv.WhatId = OppId;
            cv.Status = 'Completed';
            cv.Priority = 'Normal';                
        } 
        cvTask.add(cv);
    }  
     if(!cvTask.IsEmpty()){
         insert cvTask;

        List<Attachment> attach = new List<Attachment>(); 
        for(Task iTask : cvTask)
        {
            for(Messaging.EmailFileAttachment fl : fileList)
            {
                Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
                attachment.Body = fl.Body;
                attachment.Name = EmailSubject;
                attachment.Description = htmlEmailBody;
                attachment.ParentId = iTask.Id;
                attach.add(attachment);
            }
        } 
        if(!attach.IsEmpty())
        {
            insert attach;
        }
```

[image]

You can the task in the above screenshot. One with related to and one without related to. Any ideas about this?

Comment: The other Task has a different subject and due date as well as no related to value. So the other Task is being created by some other code or configuration.

Comment: @KeithC or the code is called twice...

Comment: @UweHeim If it was called twice the subject etc would be the same for both Tasks.

Comment: The code above could not create the task via the code you presented. Notice the space between `:` and `test` - your code does not have that. In addition, you are not setting the due date in your code yet the task (1st) has a due date. All thing point to a WFR or other code creating the task (1st). (as Keith C said, just wanted to clarify it a bit)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your helps guys.. I figured out the problem.
Its sending the email logging a activity.

```
    msg.saveAsActivity = false;
```

Setting it as false solved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Just out of my mind I can figure the following possible reasons:

1. either your code is called twice unintentionally (might happen in a trigger, schedule or indirectly via workflows) or
2. the task has been created by other code or
3. `toAddressesList` contains duplicate ids.

To debug it precisely I usually move code like that into a static method for isolation. There you can ExecuteAnonyous it, funneling parameters you control.

For verification I would also check createdDate on the new tasks to see if they are really generated in one run.

And as @Eric said: check how DueDate has been populated (by other code, manually, ...)

Comment: I just removed the send email functionality and now its working correctly. Any ideas? Because I checked the workflow rules and its doesn't have anything.

Answer (score 0):

Check the workflow rules if they have any task created from them.. As I also believe the two tasks are not from code one must be from a configuration item 90% a workflow rule.

Comment: I just removed the send email functionality and now its working correctly. Any ideas? Because I checked the workflow rules and its doesn't have anything.

Answer (score 0):

I missed this in my first answer and only your comment pointed me to that:

The function `Messaging.sendEmail()` itself is inserting a task on its own. In Salesforce emails are recorded as task and consequently while sending, task is generated to log your outbound emails.

Additionally you are creating a task in your code and writing it to the database here

```
insert cvTask;
```

This is creating a second task.